# OAuth response works as URL but can't get cURL to work in PHP

Tags: php, curl, oauth, slack-api

I'm trying to get an OAuth response to work with Slack but no joy.

I get to the point where I get a "code" var value returned from Slack that I need to include in my response.

I can manually build a URL using the returned value and send it as a response to complete the OAuth and install my app—that works every time. It looks like this:

`https://slack.com/api/oauth.access?client_id=12345&code=123.456.789&client_secret=12345678&`

The 'code' var is the variable bit, the other stuff is all static.

I know the PHP is getting the value of "code" I need because I can echo it.

Here's the PHP that doesn't work:

```
    <?php 

    $authCode = $_GET['code'];
    echo $authCode; //succeeds

    $client_id = '12345';
    $client_secret = '12345678';


    $data = array(
                'client_id' => $client_id,
                'client_secret' => $client_secret,
                'code' => $authCode
                    );
            $data_string = json_encode($data);


    $ch = curl_init('https://slack.com/api/oauth.access');

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
                );
            //Execute CURL

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            return $result; 


     ?>
```

I would like to see a new page loaded after sending the response but first things first.

This is my first attempt at something like this so I suspect I've missed an important bit that I hope someone can help sort for me.

Any alternative approach that achieves a successful result is welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things not quite right here:

1. You are providing the input parameters in JSON format but, following the OAuth 2.0 specification, the Slack API requires parameters to be provided as GET or POST parameters as documented here: https://api.slack.com/web#basics. So you should use `http_build_query($data)` rather than `json_encode($data)`, and omit setting any HTTP headers yourself.
2. the `redirect_uri` parameter is missing from the request

Comment: Thank for the reply. Yes, I discovered the `http_build_query` approach an hour or so before you posted! That works as you suggest here so I went to bed. Your answer was good to find today since it explains why it works. Added the `redirect_uri` then too but there's still an issue that I need to untangle.

Comment: CLARIFICATION: The issue with the `redirect_uri` is that it doesn't redirect to another page. I do get a valid JSON response back and it displays, it doesn't complain about a bad `redirect_uri`, but the page doesn't change.